# php5-msql installed on Ubuntu but not shown in phpinfo.php

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, php

I am setting up Nginx+PHP+MYSQL on Ubuntu 12.04.

I used

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

to install MySql module for PHP. However, everything seems to be installed and enabled, it is yet shown in phpinfo.php and I cant get the php application to connect to the MySql server. The php app is accessible, and I can view things on phpinfo.php.

BTW, mysql is running normally, because I am running an Rails app using it, so I know it is working fine.

Comment: Are you using php5-fpm to execute PHP? In that case you probably have to restart php5-fpm (using `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart`). If you are using FastCGI you probably have to kill the running php-cgi processes (`killall php-cgi`). That's because PHP reads the ini-files only when the process is started. Also: check if the mysql-extension is actually loaded: `grep -E 'extension=(pdo_)?mysql.so' -r /etc/php5`

Comment: @vstm that's answer material, you should make it so.

Answer (score 0):

As @vstm said a quick summary to help others get the answer quicker:

## 1. Kill php-cgi

`killall php-cgi`

## 2. Restart php-fpm

`/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` OR `service php5-fpm restart`

## 3. Double check with

`grep -E 'extension=(pdo_)?mysql.so' -r /etc/php5`